# Sql Query distinct records within inner joined tables

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have joined a few tables together and I am having some issues. Here is my sql:

```
SELECT co.orderid,
       orderdate,
       emailaddr,
       city,
       weight,
       partdescription
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN custorder co ON c.customerid = co.customerid
INNER JOIN custorderline cl ON co.orderid = cl.orderid
INNER JOIN inventorypart i ON cl.partnumber = i.partnumber
WHERE orderdate BETWEEN to_date('2015/11/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND to_date('2015/11/30', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
  AND emailaddr LIKE '%gmail%'
  OR emailaddr LIKE '%outlook%'
  AND categoryid IS NOT NULL
  AND weight > 30;
```

here are some results:

```
ORDERID    ORDERDATE EMAILADDR                                          CITY                     WEIGHT PARTDESCRIPTION                                  
---------- --------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
2000000351 30-NOV-15 vacation@gmail.com                                 Walla Walla                  .5 MINI TOWER CASE                                   
2000000351 30-NOV-15 vacation@gmail.com                                 Walla Walla               34.44 EAGLE Z240 XEON E3                                
2000000354 01-DEC-15 jmuench@outlook.com                                Miami                     34.44 EAGLE Z240 XEON E3                                
2000000224 07-OCT-15 findwork@outlook.com                               Asheville                 34.44 EAGLE Z240 XEON E3                                
2000000279 01-NOV-15 analyzeh20@gmail.com                               Sumter                     .438 BOARD GAMES                                       
2000000279 01-NOV-15 analyzeh20@gmail.com                               Sumter                     .375 INTERNET SECURITY                                 
2000000298 08-NOV-15 mswatson@gmail.com                                 Ogden                     27.32 EAGLE PRETIEGE 9000                               
2000000311 12-NOV-15 syarian@gmail.com                                  Whales                       .5 2GB RADEON R7 350 VIDEO CARD                      
2000000316 16-NOV-15 mouse@gmail.com                                    Charleston                 .375 FLASH WING OPTICAL GAMING MOUSE                   
2000000320 17-NOV-15 jjones@gmail.com                                   Burns                      .188 HDMI MALE 180 DEG SWIVEL                          
2000000346 29-NOV-15 sign3@gmail.com
```

here is what I am trying to accomplish. all orders in november, emails contain gmail or outlook, part numbers must have a categoryid, parts must weight more than 30, and orderid only shows up once.

my issues are that parts weighing less than 30 are still showing up and i somehow need to make it so "If an order appears more than once;list it only once."

This is a hw question that I am stumped on... I've played with it for a long time now, keep coming back to it and think I am just thinking about it wrong. Any help or insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Why does the same order ID show up with different city and weight? Which row is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add brackets to your WHERE clause to process "OR" logic correctly.

```
select co.orderid, orderdate, emailaddr, city, weight, partdescription
  from customer c
 inner join custorder co on c.customerid = co.customerid
 inner join custorderline cl on co.orderid = cl.orderid
 inner join inventorypart i on cl.partnumber = i.partnumber
 where orderdate between to_date('2015/11/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
   and to_date('2015/11/30', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
   and ( emailaddr like '%gmail%' or emailaddr like '%outlook%' )
   and categoryid is not null
   and weight > 30;
```

Also this query will not get orders later than "2015/11/30 00:00", for example it will not catch "2015/11/30 00:01". 
So you need to add **time** to format mask:

```
...AND to_date('2015/11/30 23:59:59', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

or instead of BETWEEN use

```
    orderdate >= to_date('2015/11/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
and orderdate < to_date('2015/12/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```